# Mongoose schema optional fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a user schema with mongoose in nodejs like this

```
userschema = mongoose.Schema({
    org: String,
    username: String,
    fullname: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});
```

Except sometimes I need to add some more fields.

**The main question is: Can I have optional fields in a monogoose schema?**

Answer (score 84, accepted):

All fields in a mongoose schema are optional by default (besides `_id`, of course).

A field is only required if you add [`required: true`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) to its definition.

So define your schema as the superset of all possible fields, adding `required: true` to the fields that are required.

Comment: Is it possible to set `required:true` on a couple of fields if and only if a third field has `required:true`? The use case for this is quite common... e.g. `hourlyRate` and `endDate` are required only if `isContractor` is a required field.

Answer (score 63):

In addition to **optional** (default) and **required**, a field can also be **conditionally required**, based on one or more of the other fields.

For example, require password only if email exists:

```
var userschema = mongoose.Schema({
    org: String,
    username: String,
    fullname: String,
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: function(){
            return this.email? true : false 
        }
    },
    email: String
});
```

Comment: not working with typescript it says: the "this" keyword is disallowed outside of a class body (no-invalid-this)tslint(1)
:-(

Comment: I am on a firebase function project and want the same things, even it works when I remove this "no-invalid-this" property from ts-lint file but is this correct to do so?

Comment: @InzamamMalik I'm afraid I don't have much experience with typescript. Afaik, there are no hard and fast rules about most lint warnings, so I guess there should be no harm in removing the property.

Comment: These kinds of required conditions in Mongoose are similar to check constraints on columns in ANSI standard SQL