# can i insert multiple rows with different number of columns/fields in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

## this is the schema that i want to be flexible :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const schema = new Schema(
  {
    //something goes here
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const newModel =  mongoose.model("Trash", schema);
```

Now suppose this the trick that I want to do

```
newModel.create({
    name: "name1",
    age: 24
})

newModel.create({
    name: "name1",
    age: 24,
    address: "address",
    phone: 425565634
})

//and more....
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942037/mongoose-schema-optional-fields)